# Releasing Open Source Artifacts to Nexus/Maven Central via Travis CI

Tags: maven, gradle, release, travis-ci

I am actually searching for an solution on how to automatically release artifacts for my open source projects to maven central/our company nexus. I am using Maven/Gradle and Travis CI to build the artifacts.

Ideally i just change the version of my maven gradle module to an release version, travis recognizes that and deploys the resulting artifact to nexus/maven central.

Has anyone ideas how to do that without building releases locally.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You can find a number of articles on the web for how to publish to Maven Central with Gradle.

Comment: There is a guide on the maven website that may be helpful: http://maven.apache.org/repository/index.html